# simplify the sum of this binomial coefficients -- generalized gambler ruin problem

Tags: summation, recurrence-relations, binomial-coefficients, gambling

While solving recursion $p_i = p_{i-B} (1-\alpha) + p_{i+1} \alpha$, related to a special gambler ruin problem, we came across the following summation. Let $0$ and $K$ be the extremes of the gambler ruin problem, that gains 1 per round with probability $\alpha$ and loses $B$ with probability $1-\alpha$.  Is there a way to simplify this sum of binomial coefficients?

$$p_i = \kappa \sum\limits_{l=0}^{m} 
 \beta^l \binom{l(B+1)-i}{l}$$
where $\beta= \alpha^{B}(1-\alpha)$ is a number between 0 and 1, and $i$ is a number between 0 and $K$. Here $\kappa$ is a constant that depends on $i$, $K$ and $B$. Finally, $m= \lfloor (i-1)/(B+1) \rfloor$.

Initial conditions: $p_0=0$ and $p_K=1$.

More precisely,

$$p_i = \frac{ \alpha^{1-i} \sum\limits_{l=0}^{\lfloor (i-1)/(B+1)\rfloor} 
 \beta^l \binom{l(B+1)-i}{l}}{ \alpha^{1-K} \sum\limits_{l=0}^{\lfloor (K-1)/(B+1)\rfloor} 
 \beta^l \binom{l(B+1)-i}{l}}$$

We let $\binom{n}{l}\triangleq\frac{(-1)^l (-n)_l}{l!}$ with $(n)_l$ being the rising factorial of $n$,
$(n)_l=n(n+1)\cdots(n+l-1)$.  [NIST Handbook Mathematical Functions: what is the binomial coefficient involving negative elements? what is the terminology for the rising factorial?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4759390/nist-handbook-mathematical-functions-what-is-the-binomial-coefficient-involving)

If $B=1$

$$p_i = \frac{ \alpha^{1-i} \sum\limits_{l=0}^{\lfloor (i-1)/2\rfloor} 
 \beta^l \binom{2l-i}{l}}{ \alpha^{1-K} \sum\limits_{l=0}^{\lfloor (K-1)/2\rfloor} 
 \beta^l \binom{2l-i}{l}} = \frac{1-((1-\alpha)/\alpha)^i}{1-((1-\alpha)/\alpha)^K}$$

How to verify the latter equality? How to generalize it for the case where $B>1$?

Comment: Is your sum running through $i$ or through $l$? If it is running through $l$, then what is $i$?

Comment: $i$ is a constant

Comment: What sort of initial conditions do you have for that recurrence relation?

Comment: initial conditions added to question, thanks!

Comment: @DanielS. Are those initial conditions enough? Even with $B=2$ the solution to the recurrence relation has $3$ unknown constants.

Comment: $K, B, \alpha, \beta$ are all constants, fixed and given -- what are the 3 unknown constants, @ChrisLewis ?

Comment: I'm just looking at the recurrence relation at the moment - it's a linear, homogeneous equation, so not difficult to solve, but the greater the value of $B$, the higher the order, and the more unknown coefficients in the solution.

Comment: hi @ChrisLewis yes, we can numerically solve the equation, but I'm curious about whether there is a closed form solution. In case there is a closed form, it should probably involve the simplification of the sum that I've posted in the question -- is there a way to simplify the summation?

Comment: @ChrisLewis I am wondering if there is a way to simplify the summation, to get a closed form expression for it

Comment: I suppose you need $p_i = 0$ if $i\leq 0$ and $p_i = 1$ if $i\geq K$ in order to have a fully defined recurrence, because $p_1$ depends on a term with negative index.

Comment: You have a linear homogeneous recurrence, so you can write the characteristic equation and derive the explicit formula

Comment: WolframAlpha uses the hypergeometric function to represent your sum even for small $B$. For $B=1$, we can get $p_i=\frac{1-((1-\alpha)/\alpha)^i}{1-((1-\alpha)/\alpha)^K}$ using the characteristic equation.

Comment: please, may you share the expression with hypergeom?

Comment: See [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=sum%5B%28%28b%5El%29*%28C%282*l-j%2Cl%29%29%29%2C%7Bl%2C0%2Cfloor%28%28j-1%29%2F2%29%7D%5D) for $B=1$. See [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=sum%5B%28%28b%5El%29*%28C%283*l-j%2Cl%29%29%29%2C%7Bl%2C0%2Cfloor%28%28j-1%29%2F3%29%7D%5D) for $B=2$. See [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=sum%5B%28%28b%5El%29*%28C%284*l-j%2Cl%29%29%29%2C%7Bl%2C0%2Cfloor%28%28j-1%29%2F4%29%7D%5D) for $B=3$. I used $b,j$ for $\beta,i$ respectively.