# NIST Handbook Mathematical Functions: what is the binomial coefficient involving negative elements? what is the terminology for the rising factorial?

Tags: combinatorics, binomial-coefficients, combinatorial-proofs

It is well known that if $n>0$, then https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient

\begin{align}\binom{-n}{k} &= \frac{-n\cdot-(n+1)\dots-(n+k-2)\cdot-(n+k-1)}{k!}\\
&=(-1)^k\;\frac{n\cdot(n+1)\cdot(n+2)\cdots (n + k - 1)}{k!}\\
&=(-1)^k\binom{n + k - 1}{k}\\
&=(-1)^k\left(\!\!\binom{n}{k}\!\!\right)\;.\end{align}

Here are some questions:

1. the above equations holds only for $n>0$, right? If $n<0$, we should adjust accorindlgy, but this does not seem to be clearly stated in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient
2. Frank W. J. Olver, Daniel W. Lozier, Ronald F. Boisvert, and Charles W.
   Clark. The NIST Handbook of Mathematical Functions. Cambridge
   Univ. Press, 2010. [NIST](https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Vikash-Pandey-7/post/Can-anyone-suggest-books-on-the-fundamental-understanding-of-bessel-functions-with-worked-examples/attachment/59d61e2079197b807797c859/AS%3A276097896022016%401442838276398/download/NIST_Handbook_Mathematical_Functions.pdf#page=231) it states in section 1.2 that

\begin{align}\binom{n}{k}&= (-1)^k\;\frac{(0-n) \cdot (1-n) \cdot (2-n) \dots (k-2-n)\cdot (k-1-n)}{k!}\\ &= (-1)^k\;\frac{(-n)_k}{k!}\\
&=(-1)^k\binom{ k -n - 1}{k}\end{align}

what does the symbol $(-n)_k$ mean? Is this a standard terminology? I was not able to find its meaning or interpretation in the above NIST guide.

3. do we need to take care for the cases $n=0$ and $k \neq 0$, or $n\neq 0$ and $k =0$, or $n=0$ and $k=0$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. The above equations hold for all $n\in \mathbb C$. For example,

$$
4=\binom{-(-4)}3=\frac{4\times 3\times 2}{3!}=(-1)^3\frac{(-2)\times (-3)\times (-4)}{3!}=(-1)^3\binom{-4+3-1}{3}=4
$$

2. $(n)_k:=\prod_{i=0}^{k-1} (n+i)$ is the [rising factorial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Falling_and_rising_factorials).
3. Everything works whether or not $n=0$ or $k=0$. There is no division by zero, because $0!=1$.

Comment: 2. $(-n)_k=\frac{n!}{(n-k)!}$ is the [falling factorial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Falling_and_rising_factorials).

does that imply  $(-n)_k = (n)_k$? why so?

Comment: i think $(-n)_k$ would be the raising factorial?

Comment: in the standard reference work Abramowitz and Stegun, the Pochhammer symbol (x)n is used to represent the rising factorial.[6][7]

Comment: I meant to say $(n)_k=n!/(n-k)!$. What I wrote initially, $(-n)_k=n!/(n-k)!$, is untrue.

Comment: yes, thanks, Mike! I was not familiar with the falling factorial. But now looking back at the NIST material, I think that the terminology that they use is in agreement with (n)_k being the rising factorial, not the falling factorial. Apparently, according to wikipedia https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Falling_and_rising_factorials In the theory of special functions (in particular the hypergeometric function) and in the standard reference work Abramowitz and Stegun, the Pochhammer symbol (x)n is used to represent the rising factorial.[6][7] Do you agree?

Comment: @DanielS. I made another careless mistake. You are correct, $(n)_k$ should be the falling factorial, in the context of your sequence of equations in point 2.